# Postgresql can a logical replica have DB objects of its own?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 postgresql 12 DB servers, say A and B. A is the main DB.
B consists of some Foreign tables pointing to A and some materialized views built with those foreign table joins. The materialized views refresh nightly and with increasing data, refresh over FDWs are taking awfully long as SQLs over FDWs can’t parallelized.
I wanted to know if -

1. a logical replica ( which gives me the ability to have only few tables replicated) can have some of its own objects ( mat views in my case, so that the refresh does not have to pull and join tables over FDW)
2. For those familiar with Oracle’s Golden Gate, is there anything similar for postgres? i.e log based not trigger based? open source would be better!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like logical replication would indeed be the solution for you:

- You can replicate individual tables with it, which you should not modify on B, but otherwise B is a normal database where you can have other tables.
- Logical replication works by parsing the transaction log, just like you want. So all data modifications are replicated incrementally.
- The replicated tables on B will be duplicates of the tables on A, so they are physically present on B (with foreign tables, there are no data on B, and accessing the foreign tables will actually access data on A). So there is no immediate need for materialized views.

Note that there are some limitations to logical replication. Most notable, `ALTER TABLE` and other DDL statements are not replicated.

Comment: The need for materialized views will be there in my case as they are aggregations of several table joins of A. Only thing I want to confirm is if B will be able to create tables/views/matviews of its own alongside.

Comment: Yes, the logical standby is a normal database open for writing.